# Zeroes of Complex Cosine

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the zeroes of $\cos z=2$.

Attempt:

$\cos z=\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cos(iy)-\sin(x)\sin(iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)+\sin(x)\sinh(y)=2$

I don't know how to proceed form here...

Comment: Do you mean the _solutions_ of $\cos z=2$ ?

Comment: You forgot an $i$, $\cos (x+iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y$. Look at real and imaginary parts.

Comment: $z=\arccos2$ ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe for this kind of equation it is a good idea to come back to exponentials.

So you have $e^{iz}+e^{-iz} =4$ Hence, multiplying by $e^{iz}$ you get $e^{2iz} - 4 e^{iz} +1 = 0.$ A small change of variables $Z = e^{iz}$ and you should get the solution.

Comment: After finfing $Z$, a complex logarithm must be applied for finding $z$, and this should gave infinitely many solutions.